# Save file to specific folder in C# using SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, winforms, savefiledialog

I need to save a file using `SaveFileDialog` to a specific folder.

For example, say we want to save in "c:\MyNewFolder". If the folder doesn't exist, create it and save there, or only save there if the folder does exist.

```
String fileName="";
String date = DateTime.Now.Day+"-"+DateTime.Now.Month+"-"+DateTime.Now.Year;
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialog1.FileName = fileName;
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    using (Stream s = File.Open(saveFileDialog1.FileName,FileMode.CreateNew))
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(tbName.Text);
        sw.WriteLine(tbSummary.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you specify an inexistant path? If you try to type it directly in the filename textbox you get an error message from the SaveFileDialog.

Comment: @Steve Thanks..dosent notice that, How can i correct this?

Comment: Pressing the button to create a new folder in the SaveFileDialog? As far as I know, the SaveFileDialog doesn't allow an inexistant path to be returned in Windows7, neither if you code for the FileOK event. [See this article on Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/716464/savefiledialog-checkpathexists-ignored-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 2):

You can look for

```
SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
save.InitialDirectory = "c:\\MyNewFolder";
save.RestoreDirectory = true;
```

Comment: You can check folder prior to saving file, if not exist create it. SaveFileDialog allows to select location therefore you can only start with a initial directory.

Comment: @Grx70 How can I check if the directory exist?

Comment: @user2922456 `System.IO.Directory.Exists("c:\\MyNewFolder")`, which returns bool value, although `System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("c:\\MyNewFolder")` will create the directory only if necessary, so in this case checking for existence is redundant

Comment: @JibranKhan remember to escape the `'\'` character

Answer (score 1):

```
string strPath="c:\MyNewFolder";

if (!Directory.Exists(strPath))

{

    Directory.CreateDirectory(strPath);

}

else

{

//Continue your logic and append your file name

}
```

Comment: You dont have to check if the directory exists. If the folder exists nothing will happen. If the directory doesn't exist it will be created