# Copying a file from one location into a folder in Solutions Explorer using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an asp.net project using c# and I need to copy a file from an arbitrary location which is determined by the file upload dialog box.
 I need to make an exact copy of the file in a folder that is located in the Solutions Explorer. Below is the code I am using.

```
    string filename = txt_lesson_title.text; 

string sourcepath = _Uploadedfile.PostedFile.FileName.ToString(); 

    string targetPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/destFolder/");

    File.Copy(sourcePath, targetPath + fileName);
```

The above code runs without reporting any errors but I cannot see the copied files in the destination folder. Any help will be deeply appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to copy the file, you need to save a copy of it.
You can do this
if the file is coming to your controller, you controller should have arguments like  HttpPostedFileBase or HttpPostedFileBase[] depending on if you are saving one or more

if you are saving one,

```
public ActionResult Step(FormCollection collection, HttpPostedFileBase file) {

    //HttpPostedFileBase file; //this comes from you controller argument

    var directory = "~/Uploads/";
    //this if statement can be optional
    if(!Directory.Exists(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(directory)))
    { 
        Directory.CreateDirectory(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(directory));
        var virtualPath = directory + "/" + <your file name here>;
        var filePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(virtualPath);
        //if the file exists already, delete and replace it with the new one
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
        }
        file.SaveAs(filePath);
     }
    else {
        //do as above without the create directory
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bosco. I am trying out your solution but it seems the first use the variable file as in file.SaveAs(filepath) is showing an error, "use of unassigned local variable". Any help please

Comment: @KobinaEboYankson, I have updated the code now and added the controller controller, so point the upload file form to this controller and the file will save. Please note that the update uploads only one file, for multiple files use HttpPostedFileBase[] file in the controller argument and loop through it to save individual file

Comment: please, does the controller only works in asp.net MVC? If not, how do I implement it in a non-MVC project? Forgive me for my inquiries, I am quite new to asp.net

Comment: I don't really understand non MVC. Can you give example? This works for winforms https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26944595/save-file-to-specific-folder-in-c-using-savefiledialog